# Importing S4 functions from the Matrix package

Tags: r, package, sparse-matrix, r-s4, roxygen2

The [Matrix](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/index.html) package defines a whole bunch of S4 methods for multiplying matrices, that are dispatched by the S4 generic functions `%*%`, `crossprod`, and `tcrossprod`.

How do I import the "%*%" methods, for use in my own package?  This piece of code fails when I run `devtools::document()`:

```
#' @title my function
#'
#' @description Does magic Matrix stuff
#' @import methods
#' @importFrom Matrix "%*%" Diagonal
myfun <- function(x, y){
  x %*% Diagonal(x=y)
}
```

I want to make sure this function uses the sparse Matrix multiplication methods from the Matrix package if x is a sparse matrix.  But when I run `devtools::document()` I get the following error:

```
Updating mypackage documentation
Loading mypackage
Error: object ‘%*%’ is not exported by 'namespace:Matrix'
```

Comment: Read the last section there: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html

Comment: `@import methods` did not fix my problem, nor did `@importMethodsFrom Matrix "%*%"`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use `@importMethodsFrom` and remove the quotes around the operator.  You probably also want to export the function with `@export` (you may already know this but it makes the answer more complete).  The following works for me without error.

```
#' @title my function
#'
#' @description Does magic Matrix stuff
#' @import methods
#' @importFrom Matrix Diagonal
#' @importMethodsFrom Matrix %*%
#' @export
myfun <- function(x, y){
    x %*% Diagonal(x=y)
}
```